# Problem with chaining operator<< and operator++

Tags: c++, c++11, output, operator-overloading, increment

I'm learning C++ and I have this problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class test
{
    public:
    test(){};
    test(int i):var{i}{};

    test& operator++(){++var; return this;}  
    test  operator++(int dummy){test tmp =*this;var++;return tmp;}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const test&);


   private:
   int var;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const test& obj)
{
    o<<obj.var;
    return o;
}


int main()
{
    test obj{2};
    cout << obj << endl;
    obj++;
    cout << obj << endl;
    cout << obj <<' '<< ++obj<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output i expected was: 
2
3
3 4

instead i have:
2
3
4 4

if i replace the last increment ++obj with obj++ the situation is even more weird:
2
3
4 3

it's like the stream is read in the opposite way, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine how the line

```
cout << obj << ' ' << ++obj << endl;
```

is translated.

Step 1.

```
cout << obj
```

becomes

```
// A non-member function.
operator<<(cout, obj)
```

Step 2.

```
operator<<(cout, obj) << ' '
```

becomes

```
// Also a non-member function.
operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj), ' ')
```

Step 3.

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj), ' ') << ++obj
```

becomes

```
// Also a non-member function.
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj), ' '), ++obj)
```

Step 4.

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj), ' '), ++obj) << endl;
```

becomes

```
// A member function.
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj), ' '), ++obj).operator<<(endl);
```

That's the entire line.

In such an expression there is no guarantee that `operator<<(cout, obj)` will be executed before `++obj`. It appears that in your platform, `++obj` is executed before `operator<<(cout, obj)` is executed. That explains the behavior.

Please note that the standard has changed. If you are able to use C++17, you will get the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to compile using -std=c++17 but the output remains the same. 
The gcc compiler version is 5.4.0, i don't know, but anyway i had my answers, i was just trying to figure out why.

Comment: Actually it's `operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, obj).operator<<(' '), obj++), endl)`

Comment: @0x499602D2, please see the updated answer. It's a bit different than your suggestion. Please advise if my update has any errors.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the data member i can be uninitialized if the default constructor will be used.

Either declare the data member like

int var = 0;

Or redefine the default constructor for example by using the delegating constructor.

```
class test
{
    public:
    test() : test( 0 ){};
    test(int i):var{i}{};
    // ...
```

The pre-increment operator should look like

```
test& operator++(){++var; return *this;}
                                 ^^^^^
```

In the post-increment operator the identifier `dummy` is not used. So remove it

```
test  operator++( int ){test tmp =*this;var++;return tmp;}
```

This statement

```
cout << obj <<' '<< ++obj<<endl;
```

has undefined behavior because reading writing the object `obj` are not sequenced.

You have to split this statement into two statements

```
cout << obj <<' ';
cout << ++obj<<endl;
```